# SwiftEventBus unregister swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
>     Unregistering
>     
>     Remove all the observers from the target
>     
>     SwiftEventBus.unregister(target)
>     Remove observers of the same name from the target
>     
>     SwiftEventBus.unregister(target, "someEventName")
```

Can someone explain what is target here?If its possible add some unregister code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `target: self`.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do, thus I am unsure of what your target should be.  Self will declare the itself as the target.

Comment: I want to unregister some events from SwiftEventBus with eventName but can't figure out what is target here